# Dimensions of Neural Network Output > Input

Tags: neural-networks

I would like to build a neural network which takes in $n$ rows and each row has $d$ columns. I'm wondering if a neural network can output $n$ rows with $p$ columns where $p > d$? How would I configure my network to do this?

Comment: What are the p output columns? Usually, your rows are input one at a time, and the outputs pertain to the chances that the input corresponds to each output category.

Answer (score 0):

The mathematics of this can be accomplished by use of matrices and matrix multiplication. Assuming an n by d input matrix, where each row n is a training example with d features, this can be multiplied by an input weight matrix w1 by w2 such that

```
( n , d ) * ( w1 , w2 ) = ( n , w2 )
```

where no.cols d == no.rows w1. This can then put through your hidden activation function of choice and multiplied by an output weight matrix w2 by p such that

```
( n , w2 ) * ( w2 , p ) = ( n , p )
```

I did exactly this sort of thing in an online Coursera course where the n by p output was the [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) function.

Comment: How would I determine what length w2 should be? Would the (n x w2) (w2 x p) multiplication happen in the output layer only?

Comment: @JacobChen w2 would "normally" be chosen by, for example, cross validation or some rules of thumb etc. This is where one's skill/experience etc. might be useful. The (n,w2)*(w2,p) multiplication is the output layer only.